# DYMO print label text getting cut off

Tags: dymo

I am trying to print Address label on dymo labelwriter 450 turbo
But the text is getting cutoff

I am using the below xml to format the text

```
function getAddressLabelXml()
{
var labelXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
<PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
<Id>Address</Id>\
<PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
<DrawCommands>\
<RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1581" Height="5040" Rx="270" Ry="270" />\
</DrawCommands>\
<ObjectInfo>\
<AddressObject>\
<Name>Address</Name>\
<ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
<BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
<LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
<Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
<IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
<IsVariable>True</IsVariable>\
<HorizontalAlignment>Left</HorizontalAlignment>\
<VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment>\
<TextFitMode>ShrinkToFit</TextFitMode>\
<UseFullFontHeight>True</UseFullFontHeight>\
<Verticalized>False</Verticalized>\
<StyledText/>\
<ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>False</ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>\
<BarcodePosition>BelowAddress</BarcodePosition>\
<LineFonts/>\
</AddressObject>\
<Bounds X="332" Y="150" Width="4455" Height="1260" />\
</ObjectInfo>\
</DieCutLabel>';
return labelXml;
}
```

Depending on the length and height of the text, the text is either getting cutoff on the top or on the right

I am looking for a way to auto fit the text inside the label

Thanks in advance.

[image: label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the TextFitMode value from 'ShrinkToFit' to 'AlwaysFit'